# Creating HTTP Request with graphql Query

Tags: apex, httprequest, graphql

I've been trying to add a graphql Query in a httprequest that is sent out to an api that receives the query. I've tested the query within postman and was able to get the result. However when I try to run this through apex I get this error message

`message=Unexpected token a in JSON at position 48`

Here's how I'm crafting my HTTPRequest

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
Http http = new Http();
req.setEndpoint(authUrl);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + id_code);
String query = '{"query":"query getAssetResources { site ( id: \"aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee\") { assetResources ( fields: [ \"assetBasicInfo.name\", \"assetBasicInfo.userDomain\", \"assetBasicInfo.description\" ] ) { total, items } } }"}';
req.setBody(query);
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
Map<String, Object> response;
response = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
```

I've tried using JSON.serialize on the query but with no help.

I've also tried this query, which works, so it's something to do with the ID I'm trying to add in and the double quotes (which I guess I tried to escape?)
`//String query = '{"query":"{ authorizedSites { sites { id name } } }"}';`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, so it seems that for some reason my JSON string double quote(") escaped once, but I needed (\) instead of () to fully escape that string.

Comment: Can you please share the final query that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and banging my head against the wall trying to get the syntax correct for a GraphQL query from Apex.
What worked for me was:

```
Map<String, String> mapQuery = new Map<String, String>();
mapQuery.put('query', <your query here>);
String jsonQuery = JSON.serialize(mapQuery);
```

Then use the jsonQuery as your body on your HttpRequest.
For `<your query here>` I single quoted the full value and used double quotes around for a specific ID parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The following method avoids many issues dealing with quotes when constructing your GraphQL query and cleans up the assignment of variables.

```
Map<String, Object> queryMap = new Map<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> variablesMap = new Map<String, Object>();

// Add Query using variable references
queryMap.put('query', 'query GetTask($id: ID $status: String) { getTask( id: $id status: $status ) { id status } }');

// Setup variables
variablesMap.put('id', '123');
variablesMap.put('status','delivered');

// Add the variables map to the query map
queryMap.put('variables', variablesMap);

// Turn the query map into a JSON string
String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(queryMap);

// Post request
String token = '..load_from_custom_setting..';
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndPoint( 'https://somewhere.com/graphql' );
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + token);
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setBody(jsonBody);
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```